# How to Identify Users in a Ktor WebSocket Server?

Tags: kotlin, websocket, ktor

I'm working on a Ktor application with WebSockets and I want to understand how to identify connected users. Specifically, I'm interested in knowing:

- **User Information**: Is it possible to access user information like IP address or session data within the WebSocket handler?
- **Alternatives**: If direct access isn't possible, are there alternative approaches to differentiate between connected users within the handler?

**Code Snippet:**

```
fun Application.configureSockets() {
    install(WebSockets) {
        // some configuration
    }
    routing("/ws") {
        for (frame in incoming) {
            // some code
        }
    }
}
```

- I'm open to learning about any best practices or security considerations regarding user identification in Ktor WebSockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get information about the WebSocket request, including the information about the client address, by calling the `call.request` within the WebSocket handler. Here is how you can get the client's remote IP address:

```
routing {
   webSocket("/ws") {
       val ip = call.request.local.remoteAddress
   }
}
```